# Is there a tensorflow version that is compatible with Cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.1

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I have a machine with `cuda 9.0` and `cudnn 7.1`.

I've tried using `tensorflow 1.7.0` on this machine but it does not work since this version of `tensorflow` has been created for `cudnn 7.0`
I'm getting this error when launching a training on my gpu:

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7102 (compatibility version 7100) but source was compiled with 7005 (compatibility version 7000).
```

Is there a `tensorflow` version that is compatible with my `cuda` and `cudnn` versions? I also need this working tensorflow version to be `>=1.7.0`.

I have googled this, searched every question but I never got answers for these particular versions of `cuda` and `cudnn`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be possible with `tensorflow_gpu-1.9.0`. Linked below is a table which displays compatibilities of CUDA and cuDNN with varying versions of tensorflow.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#tested_source_configurations

Comment: This link is now dead. There is a list available at  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622526/1825792 and https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems I missed some installation steps.
By installing the last version of `tensorflow`, which at the time of writing is `1.9.0`, it did work on my machine.