# Which versions of TensorFlow work with which versions of CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, cudnn

Is there any documentation about what versions of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) work with which versions of [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)?

- From their [GPU Support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) page, I see that the latest stable version of TensorFlow (1.10 at the time of writing) requires CUDA 9.0.

I need to install TF/CUDA on a PC with a slightly older graphics card (latest driver version 377.83) that supports only CUDA 8.0 (according to [this listing](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows)). Now I wonder what is the newest version of TensorFlow I can use that is compatible with CUDA 8?

Is there a comprehensive table of **compatible versions** anywhere?

Comment: Maby this will answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible

Comment: @NickyvanHeijningen thanks! How could I only miss that answer?? It didn't turn up in my searches.