# why tensorflow throws "The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order"?

Tags: tensorflow

CUDA: 9.0
TensorFlow: 1.12.0
OS: Windows 10 x64
Language: Python 3.6

Related question:[Tensorflow warning: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607063/tensorflow-warning-the-graph-couldnt-be-sorted-in-topological-order)
But there is no loop in the tensorflow graph.

My python code:

```
print(tf.__version__)
activation = tf.nn.relu
img_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3, 3, 3])
label_plh = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
layer = img_plh
buffer = []
ks_list = list(range(1, 10, 1)) + list(range(9, 0, -1))
for ks in ks_list:
    buffer.append(tf.layers.conv2d(layer, 9, ks, 1, "same", activation=activation))
layer = tf.concat(buffer, 3)
layer = tf.layers.conv2d(layer, 1, 3, 1, "valid", activation=activation)
layer = tf.squeeze(layer, [1, 2, 3])
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(label_plh - layer))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(train_op, {img_plh: np.zeros([2, 3, 3, 3], np.float32), label_plh: np.zeros([2], np.float32)})
```

Run log:

```
1.12.0
2019-01-08 16:33:09.754553: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-01-08 16:33:10.292044: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 860M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0195
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.64GiB
2019-01-08 16:33:10.292547: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-01-08 16:33:11.477348: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-08 16:33:11.477676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-01-08 16:33:11.477844: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-01-08 16:33:11.478190: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1392 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 860M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2019-01-08 16:33:11.884790: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:666] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2019-01-08 16:33:11.889780: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:666] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2019-01-08 16:33:11.917830: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:666] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2019-01-08 16:33:11.920831: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:666] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to roll back to tensorflow 1.10.0, which could solve this problem on my machine. This might be a bug of tensorflow 1.12.0.

Update: I have posted the issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24816)