# Topological sort failed when using Keras TimeDistributed layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to dot last column of lookback dimension to prior lookback period on 4D tensor (Sample, Time-steps, Lookback,features) by using keras TimeDistributed layer. The model can run normally but it throw a warning that graph couldn't be sorted in topological order when I run Model.fit().

[This forum](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24816) say that it can mess up model training. So what can I do to prevent this happen?

ENV:

1. Tensorflow-GPU 1.15.0
2. CUDA V10.0.130
3. python 3.6.5
4. Keras 2.3.1
5. Keras-Applications 1.0.8
6. Keras-Preprocessing 1.1.0

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, TimeDistributed
import keras
# Dot layer
class Dot(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dot, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):

        ht, hT = x[:,:-1,:],x[:,-1:,:]
        ml = tf.multiply(ht, hT)

        # I believe problem come from reduce_sum
        dot = tf.reduce_sum(ml, axis=-1)
        return dot

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

        return (None,input_shape[1]-1)

num_fea = 11
num_lookback = 5
time_step = 3
sample = 2

# create model
input = Input(shape=(time_step,num_lookback,num_fea))
dot = Dot()
output = TimeDistributed(dot)(input)

M = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
M.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='mse')

# create test data
data = np.arange(num_lookback*num_fea).reshape((num_lookback,num_fea))
data = np.broadcast_to(data,shape=(sample,time_step,num_lookback,num_fea))
y = np.ones(shape=(sample,time_step,num_lookback-1))

# fit model to demonstrate error
M.fit(x=data,y=y, batch_size=2, epochs=10)
```

**Warning log**

```
2020-03-05 08:36:17.558396: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.558777: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] layout failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.559302: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] model_pruner failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/time_distributed_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/time_distributed_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.560121: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/time_distributed_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/time_distributed_1_loss/mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.560575: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:533] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.560853: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-03-05 08:36:17.561141: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:697] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using TensorFlow 2.x version.

I have migrated/upgraded your code and verify that it works on google colab.
You can try to look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for more info on how to migrate your code to Tensorflow 2.x

Kindly refer to the code below

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, TimeDistributed
#import keras
# Dot layer
class Dot(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dot, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):

        ht, hT = x[:,:-1,:],x[:,-1:,:]
        ml = tf.multiply(ht, hT)

        # I believe problem come from reduce_sum
        dot = tf.reduce_sum(ml, axis=-1)
        return dot

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):

        return (None,input_shape[1]-1)

num_fea = 11
num_lookback = 5
time_step = 3
sample = 2

# create model
input = Input(shape=(time_step,num_lookback,num_fea))
dot = Dot()
output = TimeDistributed(dot)(input)

M = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
M.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# create test data
data = np.arange(num_lookback*num_fea).reshape((num_lookback,num_fea))
data = np.broadcast_to(data,shape=(sample,time_step,num_lookback,num_fea))
y = np.ones(shape=(sample,time_step,num_lookback-1))

# fit model to demonstrate error
M.fit(x=data,y=y, batch_size=2, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but this is just a portion of my code. If I change TF version, I have to change all of my 1000 line of code to TF2 and debug it again.

Comment: Hi @RonakritW. 

You can refer to the below explanation regarding that warnings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607063/tensorflow-warning-the-graph-couldnt-be-sorted-in-topological-order.

Comment: I have seen that post, but I couldn't understand where is the loop in this Implementation.

Comment: The problem might be this  ```ml = tf.multiply(ht, hT)``` . You can also check link https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24816

Comment: I also have seen this but it doesn't help, I have spent 1 weeks to find the solution, I have seen almost all available answer but non of them suggest that there is a solution. Second, multiply ht and hT does not creating a loop, if it do in the backend please show me the code or something to proof it.

Comment: Any news on this discussion?