# Which installed version of cuda installed tensoflow is using?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

Is it possible to determine which installed version of cuda installed tensoflow is using?

i.e. in pytorch I can do: `torch._C._cuda_getDriverVersion()`

Note: I'm not looking for compatibility combinations like [Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an API to check the CUDA version. But there is a hacky way, which is to print the shared library dependencies of tensorflow internal library.

```
python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib() + "/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so")' | xargs ldd |grep cuda

libcublas.so.10.0 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 (0x00007f398a94e000)
libcusolver.so.10.0 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 (0x00007f3982267000)
libcudart.so.10.0 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.10.0 (0x00007f3981fed000)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10827