# Object detection API using Tensorflow

Tags: python

I am trying to run a code for object detection using Tensorflow.But I'm getting following error when I'm running it.Help me.

```
>protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
>export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
>python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/dora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Intel Core i5-8250U , NVIDIA GeForce MX150 with 2GB VRAM...I'll correct henceforth..Sorry

Comment: which Tensorflow Version are you working with? This post helped me earlier with a similar problem ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible

Comment: pip install tensorflow==1.14

Comment: I am using tensorflow 1.14....Still I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

It's related to GPU libraries. Make sure you have installed CUDA 10.0 and followed all steps to install tensorflow-gpu

libcublas.so.10.0 file is missing in cuda folders. Please ensure the file is present in the installation folder and ensure it is in Path