# What does CuDNN compatibility error with tensorflow mean and how to fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to fix the error. Also i dont see CuDNN7.0.03 version. So please any lead would be helpful. 
**BELOW IS THE ERROR:**

> Created TensorFlow device
>   (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3093 MB memory) ->
>   physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 840M, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0,
>   compute capability: 5.0) 2019-10-14 01:12:58.508334: E
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:396]
>   Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7501 (compatibility version 7500) but
>   source was compiled with 7003 (compatibility version 7000).  If using
>   a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building
>   from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a
>   compatible version specified during compile configuration. 2019-10-14
>   01:12:58.521420: F
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:712]
>   Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(
>   conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)

Comment: You also need to tell what other dependencies and their versions are you using!

Comment: Tensorflow1.7; Tensorflow-gpu1.7; Python3.6; Cuda9.0; cudnn7.5; Windows10; Nvidia GeForce840m

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get rid of tensorflow1.7 installation if you want to use Tensorflow-gpu, so please uninstall it completely and keep only tensorflow-gpu.

Also, as I could see in your dependencies versions, it happens to require cuDNN version 7.0 with TF1.7, which is also specified in the error raised, so downgrade your cuDNN to 7.0 from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#install-windows). For all the compatible versions, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) list.

Comment: I unistalled tensorflow, and the error was tensorflow module is not found. So i reinstalled the same verison of tensorflow, and the issue fixed. I have no idea how it fixed. But i still have the tensorflow-gpu also.

Comment: it sometimes work if one has both versions, but it also conflicts many times. Good thing is your problem is solved. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rishabh Sahrawat