# Can I run tensorflow on CUDA 10.1?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run tensorflow with `CUDA 10.1` and I read that `tensorflow-gpu 1.14` supports `CUDA 10.1`.

However, when I start my script with tensorflow I got the following errors:

> 2020-02-08 17:13:14.766343: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.766512: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.766672: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.766831: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.766986: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.767151: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.775555: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
>   2020-02-08 17:13:14.775594: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...

Could anyone help me?

Comment: In order to use tensorflow-gpu with CUDA 10.1 you will have to build tensorflow-gpu with CUDA 10.1 yourself or download a pre-compiled version that was build with CUDA 10.1, it seems that the version you are using was compiled with CUDA 10.0

Comment: Do you know some source to download a precompiled version? I'm hosting my script in a remote machine owned by the university, so I can't do complex shell-stuff on it

Comment: Check out this link: https://medium.com/@fmorenovr/installing-successfully-cuda-10-1-and-tensorflow-1-14-to-enable-gpu-processing-1b220dcb23b9

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

[Here's](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) a link to the officially supported versions of TensorFlow and CUDA.

---

TensorFlow 1.14 supports CUDA 10. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) table of supported versions (it's not so up to date, but TF1.14 is specified there).