# Tensorflow 1.15 cannot detect gpu with Cuda10.1

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed both `tensorflow 2.2.0` and `tensorflow 1.15.0`(by `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0`). The tensorflow 2 is installed in the base environment of `Anaconda 3`, while the tensorflow 1 is installed in a separate environment.

The tensorflow 2.2.0 can recognize gpu based on a simple test:

```
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))

//output: Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0
```

But the tensorflow 1.15.0 can not detect gpu.

For your information, my system environment is python + cuda 10.1 + vs 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with the version compatibility of TF, Cuda and CuDNN. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible) has it discussed thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks! but it does not list information for tensorflow>=1.15.0

Comment: Hmmm, from this forum it looks like you need Cuda10.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35926

Comment: Probably. I will try that, and also the latest version tensorflow 1.15.3

Answer (score 1):

The tensosflow versions 1.15.0 to 1.15.3 (the latest version) are all compiled against Cuda 10.0. Downgrading the cuda 10.1 to cuda 10.0 solved the problem.

Also be aware of the python version. It is recommended to install the tensorflow `.whl` file (as listed at https://nero-mirror.stanford.edu/pypi/simple/tensorflow-gpu/) for the specific python version. As for installation, see [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file)

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow 1.15 expects cuda 10.0 , but I managed to make it work with cuda 10.1 by installing the following packages with Anaconda: `cudatoolkit` (10.0) and `cudnn` (7.6.5). So, after running

```
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0
conda install cudnn=7.6.5
```

tensorflow 1.15 was able to find and use GPU (which is using cuda 10.1).

PS: I understand your environment is Windows based, but this question pops on Google for the same problem happening on Linux (where I tested this solution). Might be useful also on Windows.

Comment: Can confirm that it works with cuda 10.2 too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Anaconda? it downloads all the requirements and make it easy for you with just a few clicks.

Comment: Yes, I am using anaconda 3, and tensorflows are installed on top of it.