# NVIDIA Geforce GT 540M not appearing in physical device list

Tags: graphics, gpu, card, gt

I have an ASUS laptop with built-in NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M. I have installed the Cuda toolkit and CuDNN package and other utilities like Visual C++. But whey I run this code`tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()`. only CPU is there no GPU appeared. My question is can I use this GPU for machine learning or not?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Under "CUDA-Enabled GeForce and TITAN Products" you can see that your GPU is CUDA enabled. It also has a compute capability of 2.1.

Incidentally all CUDA versions have a minimum compute capability they require.

https://tech.amikelive.com/node-930/cuda-compatibility-of-nvidia-display-gpu-drivers/

As you can see most of the latest versions of CUDA require compute capability 3 or higher.

If you'd like to try installing an older version of CUDA, make sure to check out the following link to see a list of tested OS - tensorflow -  CUDA - cuDNN combinations.

[Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible)

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry to disturb you again, I checked your mentioned links. In the second link, there is no 2.1 compute capability section and my GPU version is 388.57 which is also missing there. Can you please specify which CUDA, CuDNN and Tensorflow should I use

Comment: The second table of the second link does have compute capability of 2.0 and lower. Starting from "CUDA 8.0 GA2" and going down you can use any of those, since you have more than the minimum compute capability required. Notice that the table column is named "minimum compute capability"

As for your GPU driver version, any GPU driver version that is equal or higher to the required driver version should work. Again notice the bigger than or equal to sign used in the table.

Please tell me your OS for a cuda cudnn tf combination recommendation

Comment: ASUS A43S, i5, 2nd generation, 4GB Ram

Comment: what is your OS? is it Windows? Ubuntu? macOS?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, it is windows

Comment: tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0 - CUDA 8 - cuDNN 6 - Cmake v3.6.3 - Python 3.5-3.6

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate it if you mark my answer as the accepted answer to your question and upvote! Thank you

Comment: .........................................done

Comment: you unfortunately didn't

Comment: Sorry! I am not eligible to do that