# Can't install Tensorflow lower than 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I got this error

> AttributeError: module 'TensorFlow' has no attribute 'variable_scope'

when I ran my code and I'm searching in Google for this. They said it required TensorFlow lower than 2.0. Then I started to install it with this code in cmd `pip install tensorflow==1.15` then I got another error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15

I tried a lot of ways on the internet to find a way to solve it!
My information Tensorflow and computer

> Name: tensorflow
> Version: 2.8.0
> Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
> Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
> Author: Google Inc.
> Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
> License: Apache 2.0
> Location: c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
> Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, keras-preprocessing, libclang, numpy, opt-einsum, protobuf, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, tf-estimator-nightly, typing-extensions, wrapt

Python 3.9.7

Computer information:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU Processor @ 2.20 GHz 2.21 GHz
> Installed RAM 16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)
> Device ID 26A28871-033A-43F4-9933-B82BE00E75C3
> Product ID 00330-80000-00000-AA214
> System type 64 bit Operating system, processor based on x64
> Pen and apps No pen or touchpad for this monitor

**Thank you for your help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have CUDA11 install on your system. Tensorflow 1.X can't run on CUDA 11 unless you use Docker and Nvidia Container Toolkit.

I recommend you to use a Docker container provided by Tensorflow with the required version.

```
tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3
```

Check this post to view information about Python, CUDA, CudNN and Tensorflow version requirements:

[Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible)