# Compatibility of A100-sxm4-40 GPU

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

I have NVIDIA A100-sxm4-40 with CUDA 11.0 and Cudnn 8.0.

Which TensorFlow version can work with these specs??
I need the latest appropriate version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which TensorFlow and CUDA version combinations are compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622525/which-tensorflow-and-cuda-version-combinations-are-compatible)

Comment: @StephenC according to this chart I installed the 2.4.0 version which did not activate my GPU